# NetLogo: While/repeat turtle movement following patches-own variables

Tags: debugging, while-loop, netlogo, do-while

I want to let my turtle wander over the world and to look up for the patches with highest `totalattract` values within its in-radius patches. Turtle should wander until its `[energy] > [totalattract]` of the patch, then turtle has to stay on the patch and run a process `[infest]`. I would like to run this within 1 tick, so I suppose to use while or repeat or their combination but I can't figure out the exact syntax. The same with ifelse condition.

My example here with `while` condition just run forever end doesn't stop.

Also, I would like to measure the euclidean (the shortest) distance between patch of the beginning of the turtle movement and the patch where turtle has to stay.

Thank you !

```
patches-own [
  totalattract
]

turtles-own [
  energy
  efficiency
]

to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [
    set totalattract random 4
  ]
  ask n-of 5 patches [set totalattract 4]
  ask patches with [totalattract = 4][ 
    set pcolor red
        ]
  ask patches [
    set plabel totalattract
  ]
  setup-turtles
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-turtles
  create-turtles 1 [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor 
    set color green
    set energy 10
    set efficiency 5
  ]
end

to go
  ask turtles [if color = green [move-turtles]
    if ([totalattract] of patch-here - energy) >= 0 [beetle_infest]
    ]
  tick
end

to move-turtles    
      set energy (energy - 1)
      while [energy < 4]
[
       move-to max-one-of patches in-radius 3 [ totalattract ] ]         
end

to beetle_infest
  ask patch-here [set pcolor pink]
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that it moves to where it is supposed to, but that doesn't lead to an increase in energy, so the `while [energy < 4]` condition is still satisfied. Adding a `set energy 10` as below will break the infinite loop, but you need to change it to whatever you really want the turtle to do to increase its energy.

```
to move-turtles    
      set energy (energy - 1)
      while [energy < 4]
[
       move-to max-one-of patches in-radius 3 [ totalattract ]
       set energy 10 ]           ; put stuff here to increase energy     
end
```

Comment: Thank you for solution @JenB ! however in my real code I need to compare energy of turtle to [totalatract] of patches. I would like that turtle 1. checks its environment (in-radius), 2. move-to (or jump?) to patch with the highest [totalattract] value, 3. compare: while [totalattract] of patch-here < energy continue to move/jump, if not stay on the patch and [beetle_infest]. Please, hope it is not too confusing but how to accomplish this? Thank you again !!

Comment: You really need to ask a specific question. Which bit is not working and what is it doing wrong? For example, in this thread your question was about getting stuck in the `while` loop and that's what Seth and I answered.

Comment: Yes, that's true. the problem is that I really tried to simplify my question until the point that is not really what I wanted to ask..I posted it now as separate question